# Nested if condition is good for perfomance?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using same php page for different operation. So condition wise I am doing some actions

Which one showing good perfomance?

```
This one
    if($catid){ .. some action }

    if($sub_catid){ .. some action }

    if($sub_sub_catid){ .. some action }
```

OR This one

```
    if($catid){ 
        .. some action 
    }else{    
        if($sub_catid){ 
            .. some action 
        }else{    
            if($sub_sub_catid){
                .. some action
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't worry about performance at this minute level - it can only hurt your code and waste your time. Worry about readability and ease of maintenance now, worry about performance when you have performance issues or are ready to optimize finished code. And of course, benchmark it yourself to find out the exact answer.

Comment: Yes I finished but its taking too much time to load. So I am optimizing my codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, those two have very different meanings. The first one could allow every single statement to execute if all those variables were TRUE. The second one will "short-circuit" the first time it finds something TRUE.

What I think you're looking for is:

```
if($catid) { 
    .. some action 
} else if($sub_catid) { 
    .. some action 
} else if($sub_sub_catid) {
    .. some action
}
```

Bonus points: more readable!

Comment: Let's all go program Python and use `elif` :D

Answer (score 1):

Both have a good performance. An if check on a simple variable is very fast. Theoretically the second is faster, but you will hardly be able to measure the difference.

Semantically however, they are not the same. If both $catid and $subcatid are set, in the first situation, both the first and the second action are executed, while in the second situation, only the first action is executed.

So always be careful with 'optimizations' like this. You may make your code a nanosecond faster, but it may be less readable and it may even break!

Answer (score -1):

if your conditions cannot be true at the same time
the best way is to use the switch statement

```
switch($mycondition){

case 'category':
//Category statement here
break;

case 'sub_category':
//Another Statement here
break;

default:
//Other  cases

}
```

Comment: Rubbish. In this case, different conditions are checked. An if case won't do that, unless you write some crummy construct like `switch (true){case (firstcondition): ....`. Switch has its uses, but is quite often not the best way.